# Get a particular substring from a URL-like string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

```
$("#index-link")[0].search = "?isNameChecked=False&isDateChecked=False&isStatusChecked=True"
```

How can I find the `isStatusChecked == true` or `false` from the above string using jQuery?

Comment: Use Regular Expression...!!!

Comment: If possible post as answer using regular expression. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are several ways to do it.
One way is `str.indexOf("isDateChecked=False")` which will return `value > -1` if the string is found.

However regex might be a better option if you want to allow for variable spacing in the substrings you're checking for. For fixed strings though, I would avoid regex and go with indexof

Answer (score 0):

you may need to look at substr function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

or use search method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar question to this that provided a function which does this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values).

By modifying it a bit (assuming you want to use a string of text, not the url from the address bar) I came up with this -

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Here's a fiddle with it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/dNe38/

The value is found by using a regular expression as Pranav suggested.

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery required. Using built-in JavaScript functions:

```
var a = "?isNameChecked=False&isDateChecked=False&isStatusChecked=True";

var params = a.split("&");

params.forEach(function(param) {
    var keyValue = param.split("=");
    var key = keyValue[0];
    var value = keyValue[1];
    if(key === 'isStatusChecked') {
        alert(value); //True
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJVr2/)

Works even if you add more parameters to it.

Comment: But it doesn't work if you remove the other parameters, since the `?` interferes.

Comment: @tom You could use `a = a.substring(1)` first to delete the `?` ([`String.substring` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)).

Answer (score 0):

you can split if the string by isStatusChecked

```
var newString = asearch.split("isStatusChecked=").pop(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regexp will make a job:

```
var str = "?isNameChecked=False&isDateChecked=False&isStatusChecked=True";
str.match(/isStatusChecked=(.*?)(?:$|&)/); // ["isStatusChecked=True", "True"]
```